# Why is "ce ne sont pas pour moi" incorrect?

Tags: grammaire, pluriel

- Tu sais, je crois que les maisons spacieuses comme ça, ce n’est pas pour moi !
- Tu sais, je crois que les maisons spacieuses comme ça, ce ne sont pas pour moi !

I learned somewhere that if you have the plural noun, you need to use "ce sont". So why is "ce ne sont pas pour moi" incorrect in this sentence?

Answer (score 3):

*Ce* is a singular pronoun so the verb is expected to be at the singular too:

> ***Ce n'est** pas pour moi.*

However, as you learnt somewhere, *ce* can be followed by *être* at the plural (*ce sont*) when referring to a plural noun but this is only valid if that noun is itself following the verb and is therefore the actual subject of *être*. Instead of a noun, that can also be a collection of singular and/or plural nouns, or a third person plural pronoun, e.g.:

> ***Ce sont** des maisons pour moi.*
>
> ***Ce sont** une maison, un appartement et un immeuble.*
>
> ***Ce sont** eux* (***C'est** eux* is however frequently used  in casual French.)
>
> ***C'est** nous, **c'est** vous* (plural, but not third person.)

The last part of your sentence might then be rewritten that way:

> ***Ce** ne **sont** pas des maisons faites pour moi !*

Answer (score 1):

In the sentence:

> Tu sais, je crois que les maisons spacieuses comme ça, **ce** n’**est** pas pour moi !

the subject of the verb *est* is *ce*. *Ce* is a demonstrative pronoun, it is neutral and **singular**. It is impersonal but we can say it represents the **idea** expressed in the preceding sentence, but it does not stand for the word *maisons* itself.

If you wanted a **verb in the plural** you would have to have **a subject in the plural**, such as:

> Tu sais, je crois que les maisons spacieuses comme ça, **elles** ne **sont**  pas pour moi !

Comment: Mais si "ce" est toujours singulier, comment est-ce possible de dire "ce sont"? Selon le post suivant par jlliagre, on peut le dire: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16421/cest-vs-ce-sont-in-enumerations "Je parle espagnol et anglais, ce sont des langues que j'ai étudiées à l'école."

Comment: @sumelic Ce n'est pas la même construction.

Comment: Une anecdote à propos de *ce sont*: Balzac n'aimait pas cette construction et a, a posteriori, auto-corrigé l'ensemble de ses écrits pour y subsituer le singulier au pluriel, une fois qu'il a eu cerné la question selon sa conception de la langue.

Comment: @sumelic Mon commentaire précédent était peu clair, à la limite inexact. Ce est bien **toujours singulier**. La règle est que l'accord se fait toujours avec le sujet réel. Dans la phrase que tu donnes le **sujet réel** n'est pas *ce* (qui est sujet apparent) mais *des langues*, l'accord se fait donc avec *des langues*.

Comment: J'ai cherché la raison que Balzac invoquait pour se justifier, mais ne l'ai pas retrouvée. Je crois cependant me rappeler qu'il parlait de conséquences inacceptables et inusités du fait d'accepter le pluriel: **ce sont nous qui le disons**, ou pire encore **ce sommes nous qui le disons**. Il conclut donc que le verbe *être* devait ici être invariable en nombre et en personne. Beaucoup d'écrivains ne l'ont pas suivi sur ce terrain (dont Hugo, Maupassant, Proust, Malraux, Mauriac, Gide).