# Why say "C’est toujours les meilleurs qui partent les premiers" instead of "Ce sont ..."?

Tags: pronoms, conjugaison

> Alors comme ça, Leonardo a cassé sa pipe ? **C’est** toujours les meilleurs qui partent les premiers...

I wonder why you need to say "C’est" in the singular instead of "Ce sont", even though the plural noun "les meilleurs" follows?

> Les acrobates dans le cirque Zarlont ? Oui, je connais. Ils viennent tout juste de perdre leur chef. **C’était** pas des manchots, ceux de Zarlont... Je suis pas fâchée de m’être débarrassée de cette concurrence.

Likewise, why do you need to say "C’était" in the singular instead of "C’étaient", even though the plural noun "des manchots" follows?

Comment: See https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9371/cest-ou-ce-sont-devant-le-pluriel and https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16421/cest-vs-ce-sont-in-enumerations

Comment: Cp. English "It's always the youngest who..." Long story short, subject mismatch is very common with clefting (the name for this construction).

Answer (score 2):

"C'est toujours les meilleurs..." is a familiar form of speech which is appropriate to informal settings. In formal language you would say "Ce sont toujours les meilleurs" which has become quite formal(in a day to day use anyway).

As for the grammar issue, "C'était" as used here is an abbreviation of "Cela était" and not "Ceux-là étaient" which is never abbreviated in "c'étaient" to my knowledge. 
It is again an informal but widespread form of speech usually less appropriate in writing.

There are a lot of "grammatical mistakes" like those that are deeply rooted in french and can be pretty confusing for learners.

Comment: In most cases, using *c'est* vs *ce sont* is not considered just familiar or a mistake, even by the Académie française. There are also cases where *c'est* is the only accepted one like *c'est nous* vs *ce sont nous*.

Comment: @jlliagre Mais certainement. Comment pourrait-on prétendre le contraire?:)

Comment: @Lambie Les français ont souvent tendance à "sur-corriger" et considérer comme erroné tout ce qui n'est pas du français soutenu.

Comment: @jiliagre non je trouve pas

Comment: @Unlambder Comme le montre le pluriel *c'est → ce sont* ou le futur *c'est → ce sera*, *c'était* n'est pas l'abréviation de *cela était* mais la contraction par élision du *e* de *ce était*.

Comment: @jlliagre C'est (et c'était), c'est une expression impersonnelle, pour décrire des situations. Et pas une phrase démonstratif: C'est un crayon; Ce sont des crayons. C'est fonctionne comme "il y a". Donc, c'est invariable. Par ailleurs, on a la même chose en anglais.....

Comment: Usually when someone says "It's always the [plural] that [something]", the "it" isn't referring to the plural, but to one of them at a time.